# Run Git minus local git hooks from the command line?

Tags: git, hook

Is there a way to run git, but force it to ignore local .git/hook/scripts?  The idea is that I have a pretty heavy pre-push hook installed, but there are times where I don't want to run that hook for a small/trivial push.  I'd like to just ignore my pre-push hook in that case.

Is there a simple flag, or anything that might already be built into Git to accomplish this, or is the best idea to just move my scripts for one push call and then move them back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `git push --help`:

> --[no-]verify
>
> Toggle the pre-push hook (see githooks(5)). The default is --verify, giving the hook a chance to prevent the push. With --no-verify, the hook is bypassed completely.

So yes, use:

```
$ git push --no-verify
```

when you want to skip your heavy pre-push hook.